# Animate a visual element along an arc in MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

How do I add and animate a visual element along an arc, which I have created **inside mapkit**?

The following code will create a nice arc between two points. Imagine an animated visual that will represent an airplane flying along this arc.

```
-(void)addArc
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D sanFrancisco = { 37.774929, -122.419416 };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newYork = { 40.714353, -74.005973 };
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsArc[] = { sanFrancisco, newYork };
    //
    MKGeodesicPolyline *geodesic;
    geodesic = [MKGeodesicPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:&pointsArc[0]
                                                     count:2];
    //
    [self.mapView addOverlay:geodesic];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually it does, the animation should be bond to the mapview, when the user is zooming in and out the animation should be true to the path on the map... I was thinking of an annotation which changes ever so often with a timer , but it seems messy and inefficient. regardless I do not wish to have a top layer with animation that is disconnected from the map itself.

Comment: @chewy, The annotation might be the best option actually.  Define an annotation class with an assignable coordinate property (or use MKPointAnnotation).  Amazingly, the MKGeodesicPolyline class is kind enough to supply the individual points that it calculated to create the arc through the `points` property (gives the MKMapPoints) or the `getCoordinates:range:` method (gives the CLLocationCoordinate2Ds).  Just update the annotation's `coordinate` property on a timer and the map view will automatically move the annotation.  Note: For an arc this long, there will be thousands of points.

Comment: @Anna, Thank you. looks like a sweet clean solution. I will be ever so grateful if you will add an answer with few lines of code mostly dealing with MKGeodesicPolyline class individual points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation might be the best option actually.  Define an annotation class with an assignable coordinate property (or use `MKPointAnnotation`).

Amazingly, the `MKGeodesicPolyline` class is kind enough to supply the individual points that it calculated to create the arc through the `points` property (gives the `MKMapPoint`s) or the `getCoordinates:range:` method (gives the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`s).

(Actually, that property and method are in the `MKMultiPoint` class which `MKPolyline` is a subclass of and `MKGeodesicPolyline` is a subclass of `MKPolyline`.)

Just update the annotation's `coordinate` property on a timer and the map view will automatically move the annotation.

Note: For an arc this long, there will be thousands of points.

Here's a very *simple, crude* example using the `points` property (easier to use than the `getCoordinates:range:` method) and `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`:

```
//declare these ivars:
MKGeodesicPolyline *geodesic;
MKPointAnnotation *thePlane;
int planePositionIndex;

//after you add the geodesic overlay, initialize the plane:
thePlane = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
thePlane.coordinate = sanFrancisco;
thePlane.title = @"Plane";
[mapView addAnnotation:thePlane];

planePositionIndex = 0;
[self performSelector:@selector(updatePlanePosition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

-(void)updatePlanePosition
{
    //this example updates the position in increments of 50...
    planePositionIndex = planePositionIndex + 50;

    if (planePositionIndex >= geodesic.pointCount)
    {
        //plane has reached end, stop moving
        return;
    }

    MKMapPoint nextMapPoint = geodesic.points[planePositionIndex];

    //convert MKMapPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D...
    CLLocationCoordinate2D nextCoord = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(nextMapPoint);

    //update the plane's coordinate...
    thePlane.coordinate = nextCoord;

    //schedule the next update...    
    [self performSelector:@selector(updatePlanePosition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```